# Can't use scp to copy files for a non-ubuntu user

Tags: ubuntu, scp

I have an ubuntu ec2-instance. I have 2 users for this instance. One is the default `ubuntu` user and the other is `newuser` that I created.

I am logged in to my bastion host and trying to copy a file from bastion host to other instance for `newuser` but I am getting `Permission denied (publickey).` error.

`scp hello.txt ubuntu@10.0.1.176:/home/ubuntu` works fine.
But
`scp hello.txt newuser@10.0.1.176:/home/newuser`
gives the aforementioned error.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Amazon docs, you need to create a new key for your newly added user `newuser`. Check [this link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-key-pairs.html) where it is discribed what you need to do. Especially the `Key Pairs for Multiple Users` section should cover what you probably need.

Comment: But there we're manually adding the public key in .ssh/authorized_keys file for a particular user. what if I have to copy it from some other server with a bash script? In that case I have to use scp command.

Comment: You need to add your public key to this `authorized_keys` file, so that you can access the user account on the server using your private key.